# Can't get my footer content to center

Tags: css, responsive-design, wordpress-theming

I'm hoping for some enlightenment from a CSS whiz. Take a look at the bottom of any page at http://oicjapan.org - the address/phone info section would look a lot better in the center of the page, but I can't seem to get it to go there. Setting `text-align:center` on `aside#footer-sidebar` or `div#fsidebar` just centers the text inside the `<li>`, while the whole thing stays on the left side of `#wrapper`. And `margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;` doesn't have any visible effect on any of several elements I tried (`#footer-sidebar`, `#fsidebar`, or `#fsidebar-ul`).

I'm not limited to CSS changes - if the markup needs to be changed, I can do that.

Comment: You'd have to restructure your footer section to get it to work easily.

Comment: aRahmanS29 did come up with CSS that works, but it's not as responsive as I expected it would be (I thought inline blocks would wrap, but they don't), so if you have a markup suggestion, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `float:left;` from `#hsidebar .widget-container, #fsidebar .widget-container` or you can overwrite this rule using this:

```
#fsidebar #text-4 {
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Then, remove `float:left;` from `#fsidebar #text-4 .textwidget > div > div` or overwrite it with this rule:

```
#fsidebar #text-4 .textwidget > div > div {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none !important;
}
```

Hope this will works!

Comment: I am confused. Why exactly would you have float:none in your code?

Comment: just because your `#hsidebar .widget-container, #fsidebar .widget-container` set to `float:left;` which restrict itself to place it in the middle. Having `float:left;` will ignore `margin-left/margin-right:auto;`.

Comment: That does center it, but I'm not keen on the max-width - I would like the width of the block to be based on its contents, so that if a visitor enlarges the font in their browser, or a content admin edits the content in some way, it won't put the phone numbers under the address (that's expected for smartphones, but on a PC display it's a waste). I do see that without the max-width, the <li> becomes the width of the container, but perhaps there is another way to approach it (I don't have to use <ul>, if that's getting in the way).

Comment: float:none is the same thing as having no float in your markup.

Comment: Your new version works - thanks! Icing on the cake would have been to have the inline blocks wrap when the window width gets really small (honestly, I don't know why they don't), but you solved the actual problem I asked.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the block centered to the page, you will need to add a width to your `#fsidebar` such as:

```
#fsidebar {
    margin: 0 auto; // does the same thing as margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;
    width: 400px;
}
```

If you are wanting the block to be moved inline with the right-column of your web page, why not just margin / pad the block over?  Something along the lines of:

```
#fsidebar {
    margin-left: 350px; // use whatever looks to your liking
}
```

Comment: @badfilms nope, but given a look at the code of the site, it's not an off solution. The ideal way of doing it would be to recode it.

Comment: And I'm happy to recode it - feel free to suggest markup. Just remember that this is a CMS, not a 100% developer-controlled site, so if possible I'd prefer a layout that doesn't totally break if someone other than me changes the widget content (what's currently inside a <li>) or the number of widgets. And it should be responsive.

Answer (score 0):

Hi here's the code to center the footer text on your website, for a

```
#fsidebar {
text-align: center;
}

.widget-container {
margin: 5.0%; 
}
```